# Angularjs : how to update data from $http get server call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, rest

I have a controller which load data from a request to a server in the first time. I want to refresh data with a refresh button. The refresh button send another request with params of Request Config changed.But the problem is that the request is made asynchronously do data are not available on time. What to do to make my refresh method synchronous ?

```
function DataController($scope, $http, $location,$filter) {

    $scope.mydata=[];
    $scope.requestUrl="";
    $scope.requestConfig =[];

    $scope.loadDatas = function () {    
        var params = {
                offsetParam: $scope.offsetParam
              };
         var config = {
                    params: params
                  };

        var url='server/loadmydata/';

        $scope.requestUrl = url;
        $scope.requestConfig = config;

        //Fetch data from server
        $http.get(url,config)
            .success( function (data,config) {
                $scope.mydata = data;
                $scope.offsetParam =$scope.offsetParam + data.length;           
            })
            .error(function(data,config){
                $scope.error = data;
            });
    };

          // Refresh fonction
          $scope.refresh = function() {

            var params = {
                        offsetParam: $scope.offsetParam,
                           };

                $scope.requestConfig = {
                            params: params
                          };
            $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url : $scope.requestConfig,
                    params :params
                }).then(function(data) {

                        if(data && data.length>0){
                            $scope.mydata = push(data);
                            $scope.offsetParam =$scope.offsetParam + data.length;
                            }
                    });

          };

}
```

Here is a snippet of my view :

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in mydata ">{{data.name}} </div>
```

How to synchronize the response of refresh  ? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronize the response"?  The function being passed to the `then` function will be executed when the response is received.  That function would then update the model, which in turn updates the view.  In what way is this not working?

Comment: you cannot make it synchronous.

Comment: If you need to request the server, it cannot be synchronous. The "best" you could do is to display a spinner or any kind of waiting animation so that your user knows the data is currently being refreshed.

Comment: Want i need is just to refresh but it's not refreshing my data.

Comment: @Pracede: Define "refresh your data."  Have you tried to debug this *at all*?  Place breakpoints in your callback functions (such as the one passed to `.then()`) and examine the response from the server.  Does it have the data you expect?  Are you updating the model the way you expect?  Is there an error?  Don't just dump your code here and say "it doesn't work."  If it's "not refreshing your data" then step through the code and determine *where* it fails.

Comment: @David I see your point. However, I think that the OP here is a novice who doesn't even know what you are talking about when you throw some terms like `callback` at him.

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Agreed, but no time like the present to learn.  Especially when it comes to using a debugger.  The terminology isn't really relevant.  The difference between "it doesn't work" and "let me see if I can find out exactly where it fails" is the point here.  It's a question of putting in effort vs. relying on the internet at large to do all the work for him.

Comment: @David  Thanks for your response.I was debugging i am a newbie in angular. This is what i noticed when debugging.I place breakpoint on the callback functions ( called in then ). My request is send to server. The request return data as expected. But my data is not updated in the then callback because i did not pass in this function. To be sure that the mydata is not updated i've $watch the mydata variable and it's not changed. This is the reason why it's not refreshing but i still don't know why my callback function is not called. I did not see errors. I am checkin again

Comment: @Sprottenwels i am just posting question i am looking. I know my reply was not very clear. I did not provide many information about why it's not working and i am sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**Promise**](https://www.promisejs.org/).
<sub>(Your question suggests that you are not familiar with the concept of promises. Ignore this answer, if that is not true)*</sub>

A promise allows you to fire an asynchronous operation, and after that operation has ended, you can specify what should happen next.

There are quite a few promise librarys out there, Angular ships with [its own implementation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of [**Q**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Consider a service method that loads data:

```
loadData: function(){
    return $http.get(url);
}
```

`$http.get()` returns a promise.

You can call that function in your controller and specify another function that should be executed when the data is there:

```
service.loadData()
.then(function(res){
    // res holds your data
 });
```

Now, if you trigger an option that shows a loading spinner before you fire your `loadData()` method, you can turn that trigger off when the data has been loaded.

Here is a nice video tutorial about using promises with Angular: [egghead.io/promises](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-promises)

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/SdngDtQgbT0wDin0cNp7/preview - open your console and see an array of data